# How many solutions does this equation have? Students wanna know!

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $ax+bx+c+dx=e+fx+g$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ are the whole numbers between $1$ and $9$.

How many possible different solutions are there? I know this is a combinatorics problem. My students think there’s anywhere from $5$ to $1,000,000$ possible different ways to plug in these numbers.

Comment: "Students wanna know!" makes me wanna answer

Comment: Is that $1$ to $9$, inclusively?

Comment: @Shaun yes! Numbers 123456789

Comment: Unless those are meant to be multiple variables, the answer is there's one solution. And if they are multiple variables, surely you want integer solutions?

Comment: @JackM yes I regret solutions!

Comment: You did not state whether you require $x$ to be an integer or not. Please edit in that $1$ to $9$ is inclusive, as "the whole numbers $1$ to $9$" seems to imply to me that you use them all and you only have seven letters aside from $x$

Answer (score 3):

I read the problem to ask how many real $x$ values can solve the equation, each for some assignment of $a,b,c,d,e,f,g.$   I see in the comment that between $1$ and $9$ is inclusive. 
 Write your equation as $$(a+b+d-f)x=e+g-c$$
As long as $a+b+d-f \neq 0$ there will be a unique $x$ that satisfies the equation.  If $a+b+d-f=0$ and $e+g-c \neq 0$ there will be none.  If $a+b+d-f=0=e+g-c$ any $x$ will satisfy the equation.

For $a=2,b=3,d=4,f=9,e=1,g=7,c=8$ we get both sides zero and any $x$ will satisfy the equation.  There are an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: So maybe we could make this question a bit more entertaining by finding all possible combinations of a,b,c,f such that $a+b+d-f \ne 0$, none of them is equal to another and they're natural numbers between 1 and 9?

Comment: Notice I said a bit because it should be quite easy but it might give OP's students some insight into both combinatorics and linear algebra